# Sum square difference - What's wrong with my approach?

Tags: java, math, sum

[image]

I see most of the people just loop around to add the numbers and their squares. I tried a different approach. Using the little mathematics I know, I realized I have a very efficient solution for it :

```
public static long sumOfNSquares(int N){
   // This is the standard mathematical formula I learnt in grade 10
    return (long) (N*(N+1)*(2*N+1))/6;
}
public static long squareofSum(int N){
   // Another standard mathematical formula. I took a square of it
    return (long) Math.pow( (N * N+1) /2, 2);
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println(Math.abs(sumOfNSquares(100) - squareofSum(100)));
}
```

This uses the standard "Sum of N natural numbers" and "Sum of Squares of N numbers" formulae. Still I'm getting wrong answer. What might be wrong?

p.s. RESOLVED

Comment: What answer are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried to compare your math solution with bullet-proof loop? Also, `N * N +1` looks suspicious

Comment: SO should have another option to close: `User error`.  In this case, the user apparently placed `(` a couple of characters earlier than those ought to be.

Comment: Just a comment about debugging... when I have some baffling output I first identify what is wrong by testing each method independently. Then I drill down into the known problem code and identify where the problem is. Then once I knew exactly where the problem was it was a matter of figuring out why it didn't work. My suggestion is to become familiar with your debugger. One *problem* with the computer is that it is extremely fast, the debugger slows everything down so you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this `Math.pow( (N * (N+1)) /2, 2)`

Use braces around `N+1`

Answer (score 1):

your `N*N+1` looks wrong. * operator has a precedence over + operator hence it will be equal to `(N*N)+1`. So use `N*(N+1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
public static long squareofSum(int N){
    // Another standard mathematical formula. I took a square of it
    return (long) Math.pow( (N * (N+1)) /2, 2);
}
```

This is a prototypical case in favour of Test Driven Development.  Run a few obvious test cases through this method, and you'll save an awful lot of time when those mathematical typos creep into your code, as they are wont to do.

Gauss, who was a pioneer of series, was addicted to calculating examples.  Perhaps it was problems like this that instilled the habit into him from an early age.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use brackets() to group the operations

```
return (long) Math.pow( (N * (N+1)) /2, 2);
```

Because, in Java * has a greater precedence over + and hence if there are no brackets then N*N is evaluated first. But what is expected is that N*(N+1) to be evaluated.

Comment: Actually, the first bracket is unnecessary.  The formula is n * (n + 1) * (2n + 1) / 6.

Comment: Thanks Rob for pointing it. I have made the change to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class soq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        long N = input.nextLong();

        while (N > 2) {
            long sumSquares = 0, sum = 0, difference = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {

                sum += i;

                sumSquares +=  Math.pow(i, 2);

            }

            difference =  (long) (Math.pow(sum, 2) - sumSquares);

            System.out.println(difference);

            N = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's correct but the judge consider the time limit exc   what can I do to make it more faster

Comment: you mean the difference will be what you just wrote?

Comment: guys im sorry but I didn't understand